# Send Javascript Calculation with PHP Mailer

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I've built a bootstrap order form that calculates the total at the bottom with basic javascript. The rest of the form is all inputs and dropdowns, which email easily with phpmailer. How can I include the calculated results with that email?

```
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Notes:</strong>
</td>
<td>'.$_POST['notes'].'</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Total:</strong>
</td>
<td><span id="total"></span></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

and the js:

```
var total = (price * numGuests)
$("#total").html(total);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a hidden input on the form, place the total in that hidden input, and then it will be available in the `$_POST` variable, which you an use to fill in your email data.

Comment: if "order form"  involves money redo all calculation server side, any one could change that total if you only rely on client-side code.

Comment: @cale_b thank you... I'm having a hard time getting it to work. Here's what I have: `<span id="total"></span> <br /> <input type="hidden" value="totalSend" name="emailTotal" />' and the js: 'var totalSend  = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML`